# minimum value for mysql query_cache_min_res_unit

Tags: mysql, performance, caching

I'm trying to add query caching to my MySQL database. But it seems like my query results are too small to get cached so I tried changing the query_cache_min_res_unit to an extremely low value like 1 to test that the cache would get created. I found that the minimum value was 512 bytes(thats what the value got set to when I tried setting it to 1), is there any way to change this minimum?

Answer (score 0):

The memory allocation in the QC is clumsy.  You can't go below 512.

Do you really need the QC?  Remember that *every* write to a table purges *every* entry in the QC for that table.

Compute these:

```
Qcache_free_blocks * 4096 / query_cache_size  -- fragmentation
Qcache_total_blocks * query_cache_min_res_unit / Qcache_queries_in_cache -- estimate of query size
(query_cache_size - Qcache_free_memory) / Qcache_queries_in_cache / query_alloc_block_size
Qcache_hits / (Qcache_hits + Com_select) -- hit ratio
Qcache_hits / Qcache_inserts  -- >10 is good
```

The maximum practical size for `query_cache_size` is 50M.  More than that and the "pruning" will consume too much CPU.